# How to install a bought module in odoo 8?

Tags: module, odoo, odoo-8

I want to know the process to install an Odoo module in a self installed instance — I've downloaded the open source version and installed it on a AWS EC2 Server.- if i buy [this module (Debranding Odoo)](https://www.odoo.com/apps/modules/8.0/web_debranding/) will i get the module files?

After buying the module what do i have to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you've bought the module you should first add the module to your addons.
There are two ways to achieve this.

1. Copying the new module to the standard addonsfolder of your Odoo
   Mostly the addons are in ROOTOFYOURODOO/addons
2. Creating a new folder for your own addons First create your *new
   folder* and then copy the module into this folder. After you've
   copied the module you should add it to the configuration file. The
   standard configuration file can be found here:
   ROOTOFYOURODOO/debian/openerp-server.conf now at the key
   "addons_path" you should add your *newly created folder* seperated
   by a comma.

I personally prefer option two because it would leave the standard addons apart from your own modules.

1. Now it's time to restart your server and log in into your Odoo
   environment.
2. Go to Settings and click on "Update Module List"
3. Click on "Installed Modules" and on the right corner search for your new module and select it.
4. Click on "Install"
5. Enjoy your module

.